# The sense of term ambient in ambient monad

Tags: scala, functional-programming, terminology

[`Id`](https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/id.html#:%7E:text=The%20identity%20monad%20can%20be,values%20are%20values%20of%20Id%20.&text=That%20is%20to%20say%20that,%5D%20%2C%20and%20vice%2Dversa.) documentation states

> The identity monad ... is **ambient** in the sense that plain pure values are values of `Id`.

What is an ambient? How is the term *ambient* related to the meaning of *pure values*? Why can we say pure value *of* `Id`, when `Id` is a type constructor? Then again, is `Id` actually a type constructor or a proper type because `:kind` commands gives no output

```
scala> type Id[A] = A
type Id

scala> :kind -v Id


scala>
```

Comment: @DmytroMitin Asking a question about the use of a term in the documentation of a popular Scala library seems completely reasonable to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ambient` is not a term related to FP or type system, but rather metaphor.

Saying `ambient` they probably mean that it is wrapping existing type without actually effecting it too much.

```
val i:Id[Int] = 3
val i2:Int = i       // Id[Int]==Int
```

Saying `plain pure values are values of Id` they mean that any value of type `X` is also a value of `Id[X]`.

```
val i:Id[Int] = 3:Int
val s:Id[String] = "3":String
```

You can think of `type Id[A] = A` as a "function on type level" that returns its parameter `A`.

Something like this, but on type level:

```
def Id[T](i:T):T = i
```

There is no such term as "function on type level", but each type constructor is analogue of function on the type system level.